# Combine a formula from text in different cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

**I would like a macro to create a cell containing a formula like:**

*='X:\Documents\Database\Database files[DatafileB.xlsm]computed'!A3*

[image: See this picture as example]

So that this cell uses the values of:

- Cell B1: The indicated cell (in this example: A3)
- Cell B2: The indicated tab (in this example: computed)
- Cell B3: The indicated xlsm-file name (in this example: DatabasefileB.xlsm)
- Cell B4: The indicated file path (in this example: X:\Documents\Database\Database files)

**How can I make a macro that creates that formula in cell B5?**

Regards,
Kenny

Comment: Look into INDIRECT, but it will require the sheet be open.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a method that works cell-side is to create the formula that would combine the elements, then copy it (*sans* the "="), and create a Named Range such as `Result` which has the formula wrapped by the `EVALUATE()` function from the old Excel 4 macro commands. Then just enter `=Result` in a cell to have the... result.

Only works used in the Named Range. Typing "=EVALUATE(...)` in a directly into a cell will fail. No warnig needed about how these could go away any time:  1) it's been 27 years and they're still here, and 2) there's some evidence in MS web material to suggest a couple features require the XL4 macro language remain so short of a total re-write of the program, they will never go away. And "27 years..."

In any case, one can use this in a macro as well, directly, although one can also simply build the formula, then have VBA act on it to do the same.

Not much different than `INDIRECT()` though `EVALUTE()` works on references to other workbooks, even when they are closed, and that's a trick `INDIRECT()` isn't doing any time soon.